# Given $y^2=ce^x-x-1$ Find the orthogonal family of curves and write 2 curves from both families that pass in (2,0).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $y^2=ce^x-x-1$

Find the orthogonal family of curves and write 2 curves from both families that pass in (2,0).

$2yy'=ce^{x}-1\implies y'=\frac{ce^{x}-1}{2y}$

Then $y'_{\perp}=-\frac{2y}{ce^{x}-1}\implies\frac{y'_{\perp}}{y}=\frac{2}{ce^{x}-1}\implies\int\frac{y'_{\perp}}{y}=-\int\frac{2}{ce^{x}-1}$

Substitution $u=e^{x}\implies du=e^{x}dx\implies dx=e^{-x}du$ for getting $-\int\frac{2}{ce^{x}-1}.$

$\int\frac{2}{ce^{x}-1}dx=2\int\frac{1}{u(cu-1)}du\overset{}{=}2\int(\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{cu-1})du=2\int(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{cu}{cu-1})du=$
$2ln|u|+2ln|cu-1|+C\text{}\overset{u=e^{x}}{=}2ln|e^{x}|+2ln|ce^{x}-1|+C=-2x+2ln|ce^{x}-1|+C$

Then $\int\frac{y'_{\perp}}{y}=ln(y)=-2x+2ln|ce^{x}-1|\implies y=e^{-2x+2ln|ce^{x}-1|+C}$

$\int\frac{y'_{\perp}}{y}=ln(y)=-\int\frac{2}{ce^{x}-1}=-((-2x+2ln|ce^{x}-1|))\implies y=e^{2x-2ln|ce^{x}-1|-C}$

Find c by substitute $x=-2 , y=0$ in the first equation $y^2=ce^x-x-1 \implies c=-e^2$

Then substitute $x=-2 , y=0, c=-e^2$ in $\ y=e^{2x-2ln|ce^{x}-1|-C} \implies$ no exist $C$ over $\mathbb {R} $

I get stuck and I cant see what is wrong !

Help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the orthogonal family of curves, you need to first solve for $c$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

$ \displaystyle y^2=ce^x-x-1$

$2 y ~y' = ce^x - 1$

From the given family of curves, $c = \frac{1 + x + y^2}{e^x}$

So, $y' = \frac{x + y^2}{2y}$

Slope for the orthogonal trajectories will be $ ~y' =  - \frac{2y}{x + y^2}$

Or, $ ~2y ~dx + (x+y^2) ~ dy = 0$, which is of the form $M ~ dx + N ~ dy = 0$.

To solve the above differential equation, note that it is not exact $(M_y \ne N_x)$ so first find an integrating factor that makes it exact, which in this case is $ \frac{1}{\sqrt y}$.

Multiplying by the integrating factor,

$2 \sqrt y ~ dx + \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt y} + y^{3/2}\right) dy = 0$

As $M_y = N_x$, it is now exact and integrating, we get the solution

$2 x \sqrt y + \frac 25 y^{5/2} = C$

To get two curves from both families that pass through the point $(2, 0)$, plug in $x = 2, y = 0$ in the equation of curves and find values of $c$ and $C$.